# MUI Icon button show border when clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have used an Iconbutton for my website but when it is clicked it shows a border & the animation is also gone. Also, I would like to know how to assign functions to my + / - buttons to increase & decrease the value in the text input. following is my full code. I get the NaN in

[image: clicked the button]

**Code**:

```
export class BookingSummary extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          seatPrice: [],
          dataLoaded: false,
          priceList :[],
        };
      }

    state = { value: 0 };

      onPlusClick = () => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, value: this.state.value + 1 });
      };
      onMinusClick = () => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, value: this.state.value - 1 });
      };

        render () {
                return (
                                        <IconButton
                                            onClick={this.onMinusClick}
                                            aria-label="minus"
                                            style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                                        >
                                        <RemoveCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                                        </IconButton>
                                        <TextField
                                            value={this.state.value}
                                            id="outlined-adornment-small"
                                            // defaultValue="50"
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            size="small"
                                            style={{ width: 48, height: 35 }}
                                            labelWidth={0}
                                        />
                                        <IconButton
                                            onClick={this.onPlusClick}
                                            aria-label="plus"
                                            style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                                        >
                                            <AddCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                                        </IconButton>
```

Comment: Could you share the sample of your code in sandbox or stackbiltz?

Comment: UI elements that are interactable will typically have a focus ring as part of accessibility so users know what is focused and they are currently interacting with. If you need us to delve deeper into any issue then you need to provide ore context and actually state what an issue is, any debugging you've done already, and expected vs actual results/observations. I running codesandbox that reproduces any issues is beneficial.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-mountain-v9fdm?file=/src/App.js
please check the sandbox. is it possible to change the numbers in the Input field when plus & minus icon clicked?

Comment: @RyanFonseka You can change its value with a state declaration. But I don't see any border when I click on the minus and plus button!

Comment: @RyanFonseka I added the state. Please see this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-banzai-v0vph

Comment: @MajidMohammadi it's working fine on sandbox. but in my project, it shows. i don't know why?

Comment: Are you running a different version of material-ui, or React, or anything else that is different locally from the codesandbox? Browser?

Comment: @DrewReese i'm really new to React i don't know advance stuff

Comment: @MajidMohammadi I render this in a class component. what should I use? instead of React.useState?

Comment: @RyanFonseka Would you like to render the sample in a class component? useState hook in functional component is same as setState in classify component.

Comment: @RyanFonseka You asked something else in your question which I can't see in the sandbox!

Comment: @MajidMohammadi apologize for the confusion. my main problem is when I use the above code in my project it shows a border when I clicked on the buttons. second is the incremental button process

Comment: @RyanFonseka Would you like to use it as the classify component?

Comment: @MajidMohammadi yes, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your aim with predifined [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in classify component. Also you need to use `onClick` for `IconButton`s. When user clicks on the buttons, you should change the value of the counter. Here's the classify component which you would like to implement:

```
import React from "react";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import RemoveCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RemoveCircle";
import AddCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircle";
import "./styles.css";

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };
  onPlusClick = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, value: this.state.value + 1 });
  };
  onMinusClick = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, value: this.state.value - 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="st_dtts_bs_wrapper float_left">
                <div className="st_dtts_bs_heading float_left">
                  <p>Booking summary</p>
                </div>
                <div className="st_dtts_sb_ul float_left">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      movieData.seats
                      <br />( 5 Tickets ) ODC <span>Rs .50</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Child Tickets
                      <br />( 2 Tickets ) ODC <span>Rs .5 </span>
                      <br />
                      <br />
                      <IconButton
                        onClick={this.onMinusClick}
                        aria-label="minus"
                        style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                      >
                        <RemoveCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                      </IconButton>
                      <TextField
                        value={this.state.value}
                        id="outlined-adornment-small"
                        defaultValue="50"
                        variant="outlined"
                        size="small"
                        style={{ width: 48, height: 35 }}
                        labelWidth={0}
                      />
                      <IconButton
                        onClick={this.onPlusClick}
                        aria-label="plus"
                        style={{ marginTop: 15 }}
                      >
                        <AddCircleIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                      </IconButton>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      Handling fees <span>Rs. 25</span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="st_dtts_sb_h2 float_left">
                  <h3>
                    Sub total <span>Rs. 55</span>
                  </h3>
                  <h4>
                    Current State is <span>Colombo</span>
                  </h4>
                  <h5>
                    Payable Amount{" "}
                    <span style={{ color: "#ff4444" }}>Rs. 555</span>
                  </h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return <MyComponent />;
}
```

[image: Edit stoic-williamson-qlhcg]

Comment: when i add this is gives me a value called "Nan" in the TextField

Comment: @RyanFonseka Did you define initial value for state?   `state = { value: 0 };`

Comment: Did you add  `value={this.state.value}` to the `TextField`?

Comment: @RyanFonseka Please share your code to debug. It seems you've done something which cause unforeseen incidents.

Comment: @RyanFonseka There isn't any errors in the code I've shared in the sandbox.

Comment: @RyanFonseka What is         `this.state = { seatPrice: [], dataLoaded: false, priceList :[], };` in the constructor? Do you have any other states? If yes, you should remove `state = { value: 0 };` and instead of that, add `value` to `this.state = { seatPrice: [], dataLoaded: false, priceList :[], value:0 };`

Comment: thanks. it was the error. silly me. apologize for the inconvenience. really appreciate your help. Good luck for you!! 